# Is there an hybrid app framework which is HTML-CSS-JavaScript → all vanilla and if so what is it?

Tags: javascript, html, framework, css, mobile

I need an Hybrid app framework which is  HTML-CSS-JavaScript → all vanilla, that would allow me to develop hybrid applications usable in both Desktop computers (laptops or otherwise) and pocket computers (smartphones or otherwise).

These apps should be able to

- Run on a LAMP server environment
- Work both natively and in browsers while sharing the exact same database
- A smartphone native version will look 100% the exact same as the smartphone native browser version by design principle

**Is there an hybrid app framework which is HTML-CSS-JavaScript → all vanilla and if so what is it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[React](https://reactjs.org)** uses native Javascript. Use it with **[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)** for mobile apps. If you need to package Desktop apps as well then maybe packaging the React app with [Electron](https://electronjs.org) might be an option.

Comment: I also have a book recommendation for you covering this stack: "Javascript everywhere". The "everywhere" stands for frontend, backend, mobile. https://www.jseverywhere.io .

(the paper version isn't released yet, but you can read an early version on the oreilly.com learning platform with a free trial account).

This is a real recommendation, I'm in no way associated with the author/publisher.

Comment: Hello, thanks; please only clarify what you mean by packaging an app with Electron framework.

Comment: [Electron](https://electronjs.org) lets you package web apps (html/css/javascript) into Desktop apps for Windows, MacOS, Linux (`.exe`, `.app`, etc). This allows you to do some things that aren't possible in the browser (i.e. accessing the local file system or running shell commands with javascript). It is based on Chrome. Think of it in a simplified way like: It creates an executable for you (i.e. `yourapp.exe`) that contains a hidden chrome installation that runs your web application (in the simplest case: `index.html`). Famous example: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)